# Webpack hot reload do normal reload

Tags: node.js, webpack

I can't understand why hot reload property not working.

These is my full config:

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = (env, argv) => {
  return {
    mode: argv.mode,
    entry: './src/app.js',
    output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
      filename: '[name].[chunkhash:8].js',
    },
    devServer: {
      port: 3000,
      open: true,
      hot: true,
    },
    target: 'web',
    optimization: {
      splitChunks: {
        chunks: 'all',
      },
      runtimeChunk: "single",
    },
    plugins: [
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: path.resolve(__dirname, 'static', 'index.html'),
      }),
    ]
  }
}
```

Start project like this: `webpack serve --mode development`

When i do change, all page reload. What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you provide a code repo?